# filter jquery results based on name

Tags: jquery

I understand how to select an element based on name.  What if instead, I already had some select results, and then wanted to find the element whose name is "bla" without performing another jquery select?

```
var inputs=$('#dialog-addPoint form').find(':input');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to filter your result set down, instead of running another `find()`, you could use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var filtered = inputs.filter('[name=bla]');
```

Comment: This actually works, but I don't understand why `.find()` wouldn't as well.  See my comment on Mohamed-Yousef's post.  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 `.find()` only searches descendants, `.filter()` works at the top level.

Comment: @dave  Shouldn't `.find()` also return the input of given name (albeit maybe give more results)?

Answer (score 2):

you can find it using **[name="bla"]**

```
var inputs=$('#dialog-addPoint form').find('[name="bla"]');
```

or you can use without need **.find()** .. say if you looking for input with name bla  .. you can use

```
var inputs=$('#dialog-addPoint form input[name="bla"]');
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work.  `console.log(inputs,inputs.find('[name=name]'),inputs.find('[name="name"]'),inputs.filter('[name=name]'))` returns `Object[input property value = "TEST" attribute value = "null", input property value = "123" attribute value = "null", select, input#CSRF attribute value = "fa0786d80f4cec9a6f6bd074...41bdcb7d472f83253e6aaee", input#guid attribute value = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"] Object[] Object[] Object[input property value = "TEST" attribute value = "null"]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/pL0n4jyc/1/ .. and that depending of what to trying to do .. say you want get attr from all inputs with name="name"?? Is that what you looking for??

Comment: @user1032531 you can look at this as well  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/pL0n4jyc/2/  .. so you can use it like demo in a previous comment  or like demo here .. again depending on what you trying to do

Comment: Yes, I know how to do the initial select based on name.  I was looking for your first approach.  http://jsfiddle.net/1w6fok81/2/

Comment: @user1032531 as I can see in demo and comments with Chris .. .find()  looking for childeren  but .filter is looking for the same element http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/1w6fok81/4/