# How to filter a TextBox accept only english alphabetic characters In jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox and I want filter it  by english alphabetic characters In jquery.any help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter jquery results based on name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635607/filter-jquery-results-based-on-name)

Comment: <input name="testtext" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/g,'');">

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot it's diffrent a little

Comment: @MohsenZahedi where is the *source code* of your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

```js
   $('.acceptalpha').bind('keyup blur',function()
{ 
       var thistext = $(this);
       thistext.val(thistext.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="text" id="acceptalpha" class="acceptalpha">
```

Comment: @Mohsend You can marked it completed if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#mytextbox").on("keypress", function(event) {

    // Disallow anything not matching the regex pattern (A to Z uppercase, a to z lowercase and white space)
    // For more on JavaScript Regular Expressions, look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
    var englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace = /[A-Za-z ]/g;

    // Retrieving the key from the char code passed in event.which
    // For more info on even.which, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3050984/114029
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

    //alert(event.keyCode);

    // For the keyCodes, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781360/114029
    // keyCode == 8  is backspace
    // keyCode == 37 is left arrow
    // keyCode == 39 is right arrow
    // englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key) does the matching, that is, test the key just typed against the regex pattern
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key)) {
        return true;
    }

    // If we got this far, just return false because a disallowed key was typed.
    return false;
});

$('#mytextbox').on("paste",function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
});
```